# "LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares" with eleanor.py

Tags: data-analysis, python, photometry

I'm doing some tests with [eleanor](https://adina.feinste.in/eleanor/) module (i'm a novice). I'm using the example code written on eleanor.py website

```
from IPython.display import Image
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import eleanor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

eleanor.Update(sector=1)

star=eleanor.Source(tic=38846515, sector=1)
print ('-------------------------------------')
print ('-------------------------------------')
print ('-------------------------------------')
print ('')
print ('')
print ('Found TIC {0} (Gaia {1}), with TESS magnitude {2}, RA {3}, and Dec {4}'
.format(star.tic, star.gaia, star.tess_mag, star.coords[0], star.coords[1]))

data = eleanor.TargetData(star, height=15, width=15, bkg_size=30, do_psf=True, do_pca=True, regressors='corner')

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

q = data.quality == 0

plt.plot(data.time[q], data.raw_flux[q]/np.nanmedian(data.raw_flux[q])+0.06, 'k')
plt.plot(data.time[q], data.corr_flux[q]/np.nanmedian(data.corr_flux[q]) + 0.03, 'r')
plt.plot(data.time[q], data.pca_flux[q]/np.nanmedian(data.pca_flux[q]), 'g')
plt.plot(data.time[q], data.psf_flux[q]/np.nanmedian(data.psf_flux[q]) - 0.02, 'b')
plt.ylabel('Normalized Flux')
plt.xlabel('Time [BJD - 2457000]')
plt.title('WASP-100')
plt.show()
```

After running the program, it find the star with its magnitude and coordinates, but appears this error:

```
LinAlgError Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\gabri\OneDrive - Università degli Studi di Padova\Desktop\eleanor prova.py in
23
24
---> 25 data = eleanor.TargetData(star, height=15, width=15, bkg_size=30, do_psf=True, do_pca=True, regressors='corner')
26
27 plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\eleanor\targetdata.py in init(self, source, height, width, save_postcard, do_pca, do_psf, bkg_size, aperture_mode, cal_cadences, try_load, regressors, language)
227 self.create_apertures(self.tpf.shape[1], self.tpf.shape[2])
228
--> 229 self.get_lightcurve()
230
231 if do_pca == True:

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\eleanor\targetdata.py in get_lightcurve(self, aperture)
623 norm = np.nansum(self.all_apertures[a], axis=1)
624 all_corr_lc_pc_sub[a] = self.corrected_flux(flux=all_raw_lc_pc_sub[a]/np.nanmedian(all_raw_lc_pc_sub[a]),
--> 625 bkg=self.flux_bkg[:, None] * norm)
626 all_corr_lc_tpf_sub[a]= self.corrected_flux(flux=all_raw_lc_tpf_sub[a]/np.nanmedian(all_raw_lc_tpf_sub[a]),
627 bkg=self.tpf_flux_bkg[:, None] * norm)

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\eleanor\targetdata.py in corrected_flux(self, flux, skip, modes, pca, bkg, regressors)
1235 f = np.arange(0, brk, 1); s = np.arange(brk, len(self.time), 1)
1236
-> 1237 lc_pred = calc_corr(f, cx, cy, skip)
1238 corr_f = flux[f]-lc_pred + med
1239

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\eleanor\targetdata.py in calc_corr(mask, cx, cy, skip)
1175 # temp_lc = lightcurve.LightCurve(t, flux).flatten()
1176 tmp_flux = np.copy(flux[np.isfinite(flux)], order="C")
-> 1177 tmp_flux[:] /= savgol_filter(tmp_flux, 101, 2)
1178 SC = sigma_clip(tmp_flux, sigma_upper=3.5, sigma_lower=3.5)
1179

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal_savitzky_golay.py in savgol_filter(x, window_length, polyorder, deriv, delta, axis, mode, cval)
333 x = x.astype(np.float64)
334
--> 335 coeffs = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, deriv=deriv, delta=delta)
336
337 if mode == "interp":

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal_savitzky_golay.py in savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, deriv, delta, pos, use)
135
136 # Find the least-squares solution of A*c = y
--> 137 coeffs, _, _, _ = lstsq(A, y)
138
139 return coeffs

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in lstsq(a, b, cond, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, check_finite, lapack_driver)

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

I tried to find solutions, like installing numpy and scipy from conda, but they did not solve the problem. Anyone know how to deal with it?

**EDIT:**
I solve the issue by creating a conda environment, but if I run the program with py IDLE it crashes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I installed eleonor and ran your code - similar but deleted the line:

> eleanor.Update(sector=1)

Because it was giving me an error. And it runs without issues.
Attached I post my output. I’m guessing you must have some problems with the packages themselves. I can't pinpoint what, but my naive advice would be to create a conda environment (I can try and help if you need). In this new and empty conda environment, you install the packages that you import (as you did before), then give it a run.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the int. I tried also without "eleanor.Update(sector=1)". Now I try one more time otherwise I'll create a conda environment.
I posted the same post on eleanor github, hope they can find the issue inside the module.

Comment: I deleted the line but the issue remains.I try with conda environment

Comment: Did you create a new conda env, activate it and installed the packages again? (Sometimes I forget to activate it ...)

Comment: I solve it by creating a conda environment. Thank you so so so much!!
Still, by running the file with py idle it give me the same issue. Dunno
Thx again!

Comment: Great! Sometimes by using the "not-conda env" python, when installing packages such as eleanor there are conflicts with other packages (for example a previous package you installed may require version 1.xx of some package and eleanor requires version 2.xx) since it can't always satisfy both at the same time, it may not install everything as elanor would want it, and then gives errors.

Comment: Oh ok, got it! Thank you so much!!